# WebGL, optimizing geometry calculation on web worker

Tags: javascript, optimization, webgl, web-worker

Hy, I´m developing a webgl application that needs to generate a lot of 2d-geometry e.g polylines, complex polygons on the fly. Currently the used vertices / colors / indices / texcoords are preallocated and then calculated according to the users input within the main update loop.

I try to recycle as much as possible ,eg. when drawing 150000 circles, I try to make sure the geometry / colors / texcoords / indices are only calculated once, unless the basic parameter (circle detail,...) do not change, and then translate, scale(x&y), rotate the vertices, (shift the indices & set the vertices color) of this 'circle blueprint' x times the amount specified by the user.
Afterwards the data is send with a single drawArrays/drawElements call. Drawing polylines and other primitives is handled similar.

While this is already quite fast, a lot of time is obviously spent on transforming the original vertices to their new positions and dimensions, sometimes leaving only a small amount of ressources the user could use to actually construct something to display.
So I asked myself how could I outsource those 'simple' calculations. Before thinking about doing it the gpgpu way, i thought about moving those calculations to a web worker.

*So this is what i had in mind:*

1. main thread: user sends request to draw 150000 circles, supplies dimensions, transformations and color
2. main thread: request is pushed to a draw request queue
3. main thread: request data is send to a web worker (if the worker hasnt started or is finished with the previous queue items)
4. web worker:  is using a large enough preallocated set of data to construct the geometry and transform it
5. web worker:  transfers the transformed Float32Array vertex,color data and Uint16Array index data via 
   transferable objects to the main thread
6. main thread: onWorkeRequestProcessed: get data send by worker, send to the glDrawArrays/glDrawElements call,
   send the data back to the worker
7. web worker:  receives data back, sends 'ok, everthing back in place, im ready for another request' msg to main thread
8. main thread: shift the queue, send the next request from the front

...
And so at the end theres hopefully more resources available to the main thread to do some user initiated calculations.

Doing it this way implies that the main loop always has to wait till the worker completely processed the queue lineary to draw everything in the right order, which at the end may render the advantages of using a worker obsolete.

Here is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/automat/8566773 (without the webgl part, just the message queue, and no main loop, because syncing framestep and waiting for the worker is an issue as well)

Btw.: Fake instancing geometric entities via textured quads is not an option.

You can take a look at the project here: https://github.com/automat/canvasGL.js (src/gl/cglContext.js should be particularly interesting)

Is this any good? Any hints appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on graphic pipelines back in the days when your average poly muncher was a set of VME racks costing about $1.000.000 and barely able to spit 10K polys 50 times per second. What follows is a very sketchy and rough outline off the top of my head, but I have written the software that made it work and I'm quite certain this way to go does get the job done in a reasonably efficient way.

Basically what you need here is a good data dependency analysis.

If you want to gain some computational power, you have to spawn worker threads ***on as many CPU cores as possible***. Yur problem is a perfect case of easy parallelization, since there is no dependency between each geometric primitive you want to compute.

Here it seems your main thread will have nothing left to do except twiddle its virtual thumbs waiting for your worker to finish his circle munching business. You will avoid blocking the browser user interface, but gain nothing in terms of CPU power.

However, what you could do is the following:

- divide your circles into sizeable packets (let's say 100 circles apiece, for 150 packets of 100 circles in all).
  put all these packets into a common input queue
- have an instance of the same worker thread running on each one of your CPUs
- each worker thread will pick the next available packet from the common input queue, process it and put the result back into a common output queue.
- have the main thread grab the packets from the output queue and feed them to the hungry GPU.

With this architecture, you will have all your CPUs running at full speed doing real parallel computations on the circles.

The common queue will act as a simple, automatic load balancer.
Imagine for some reason that some circles are more costly to compute than others. The unfortunate CPU that has got a though to crunch packet will simply spend more time processing it while its siblings will pop more faster packets out of the queue.
It's just like the workload balancing that occurs at the desks of your average post office, when several desks serve a single queue of customers.

The pipeline leading from your high level software to the GPU will start to fill as soon as the first batch of 100 circles have been processed. The CPU where your main application run will likely spend very little time feeding the GPU and the worker thread will have nearly 100% of the CPU time free to do the same computations as its siblings running on dedicated CPUs.

The total computation time will be nearly divided by the number of CPUs available on your system (give or take 5% lost in synchronization and other background noise).

The global synchronization of the whole pipeline will require some thought, but basically you know how many packets of data are generated for a given frame, so you can easily count the number of packets transiting through your input and output queue, and thus determine when a given image generation cycle is over.

Beware, though: this assumes your packets of circles can really be computed independently, i.e. they rely solely on global informations for the current frame (typically a camera position and a few lighting parameters).
If you have to do things like global occlusion culling, you can kiss your parallel processing goodbye (unless you design specialized parallelizable algorithms for that, of course).

EDIT:

I ran some basic tests to see if the workers were taking full advantage of the other CPUs. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78dWz/1/) where 9 or 10 workers are constantly running in a tight loop.

This was tested on FireFox, but failed to run on IE11 due to security restrictions using a blob to create the worker code. I only used this hack in order to fit the demo into a JSFiddle. I suppose the code should run fine on IE11 if you use a regular .js file.

```
<script id='worker' type='worker'>
onmessage = function (e)
{
    // eat 100% CPU for the requested number of seconds
    var done = Date.now()+e.data*1000;
    while (Date.now() < done) { /* wasting CPU here */ }

    // signal done
    postMessage('');
};
</script>
```

For some reason the CPUS do not seem to be fully occupied. It might have something to do with my dummy waiting loop, or it might be the worker allocation not taking full advantage of the multicore.
According to what I understood from Mozilla documentation, the workers should be spawned on multiple cores, but there is no way you can control that, as far as I know.

Anyway, this might be a basis for some performance tests, if you use real computations instead of dummies. And of course you should use direct data access, or else the message copy will ruin a good part of the benefits of sharing data among workers.

Comment: That's not quite true. Pushing the work to the worker keeps the main page responsive. If it takes 500 to 10000ms to compute some geometry, if you do that on the main page, unless you write some progressive event driven generator the webpage is frozen for 500 to 10000ms. The user can't do anything. If on the other hand you push that work to the worker the page can continue to be responsive to user input. It doesn't even matter if there are 2 CPUs or not, as workers are threads that will still mean your main page will have a chance to respond to user input.

Comment: @gman ??? what does the user interface have to do with all this? Obviously the CPU-intensive work will be done in other threads, one way or another. The only thing the user interface thread has to do is control the whole computation chain: start/stop it and pass it user inputs (camera moves, player displacement or whatever).

Comment: We're talking WebGL so we're in a browser. Let's stay there is a slider on the screen for radius. If it takes 10000ms (10 seconds) to generate a sphere then for the entire 10 seconds the slider becomes unresponsive. If on the other hand the sphere is being computed on a worker the slider remains responsive. It might be 10 seconds until a sphere the correct size shows up be at least the slider is not stuck for 10 seconds. The user can also update other things, text fields, other sliders, etc. But only if the geometry is computed in a worker or broken up into small events.

Comment: The point is even if the total time to generate the geometry is no faster in a worker there are still reasons to move slow operation to workers. Browsers run single threaded from the point of view of the main page. If JavaScript is running in a hard loop the page is frozen. You need to give control back to the browser every few ms or else it can't respond to user input in the page. Here's a sample http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/r26mx/

Comment: Interesting discussion. Ill give it a try and split the tasks across several web workers.

Comment: @gman I don't know what you're talking about. Your code is blocking the user interface, so no wonder the user interface does not respond. There is no yeld at all, since JavaScript is not interruptible. Obviously the computation has to take place in some worker. I just meant using only one worker is a blank operation in terms of taping power from other CPUs. Here is a fiddle with [9 worker threads wasting CPU constantly](http://jsfiddle.net/78dWz/1/) and there is not a glitch in the user interface.

Comment: Sorry if I'm failing to make my point. You wrote *"Using a worker thread on another CPU is olny useful if you have some computation-heavy task to do on your own CPU and there is no dependency between the data handled by each CPU at a given time."*. I'm saying workers are also useful for keeping the UI responsive regardless of the dependency issues.

Comment: @gman Sorry, I did not mean to be rude. I think what happened is, you read a previous version of my post where I was not explicit enough about the necessity of having a worker thread. That's why I did not understand why you seemed to want to make a point that I had already covered. I will update this sentence to be more explicit. Sorry about the misunderstanding.